# why Rubocop and Foodcritic is not installing I used Ruby 2.3.1p112 I install Rake also

Tags: ruby, linux

It is Showing Error as

```
root@DESKTOP-L0VTSD5:~# gem install rubocop
Fetching: jaro_winkler-1.5.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rubocop:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.1/ext/jaro_winkler
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180608-55-ednv9v.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.1/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR=" clean
sh: 1: make: not found

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.1/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR="
sh: 1: make: not found

make failed, exit code 127

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/jaro_winkler-1.5.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: and how is this a Python question exactly ??? (tag removed, and downvoted for tag spamming).

Answer (score 1):

`jaro_winkler` (which is a dependency of rubocop) need native build tools installed (like gcc, make, etc.)  How you do this depends on your linux distribution and package management tools.

If you are using Debian or Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

For RedHat/RHEL/CentOS, something like this should work

```
yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
```

You will need to be root (or use `sudo`) to perform these commands.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any Solution for it because I am very new in these.

Comment: what version of linux  are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and thanks for suggestion but i still get same error.

Comment: You also need to install ruby-dev:

Debian-based:
`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

RedHat-based:
`sudo yum install ruby-devel`